# How to send an image as a node HTTPS response with raw data

Tags: node.js, express, request, buffer, jpeg

I'm writing a path in my node HTTPS server that returns an image. The problem is I'm getting this image from another external API call (the image data exists in res.body). This image grab is basically a proxy to another API that returns an image.

I've printed out the response to the external API and I see the image data. It also opens up the image in postman, but when I make the call with my Node server acting as a proxy, I either get failure responses or the picture does not show up. The most common error in my attempts is a 'parse error' in postman trying to display the image.

The logical flow is that I make a call to the API with the image. If the response is a 200 I grab that response information and set it as the response from my node server. The code is below:

```
function axisGetImage(command, webResponse){

  var commandURL = config.CameraIP;
  commandURL += '/GrabImage';

 //console.log(commandURL);
  const options = {
    'auth': {
      'user': username,
      'pass': password,
      'sendImmediately': false
    }
  }
  console.log(commandURL);

  request.get(commandURL, options, function(err, res, body){
    if(res.statusCode == 200){
      console.log(res.headers);
      //webResponse.setHeader('content-type', res.headers['content-type']);
      webResponse.setHeader('content-length', res.headers['content-length']);
      webResponse.setHeader('cache-control', res.headers['cache-control']);
      webResponse.setHeader('pragma', res.headers['pragma']);
      webResponse.setHeader('connection', res.headers['connection']);
      webResponse.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":res.headers['content-type']});
      var base64data = Buffer.from(res.body).toString('base64');
      //body.write(res.body);
      console.log(webResponse.headers);
      //webResponse.write(base64data);
      webResponse.end(base64data);
    }else{
      webResponse.end('Image pull failed');
    }
    console.log(res.statusCode);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: When you set your options for the initial request to the external server, specify that there is no encoding in the request:

```
  const options = {
    'auth': {
      'user': username,
      'pass': password,
      'sendImmediately': false
    },
    encoding: null
  }
```

Then you can simply write the body the request returns (the image data) directly to the response of your node server, thus proxying a request for an image.

```
request.get(commandURL, options, function(err, res, body){
    if(res.statusCode == 200){
      webResponse.setHeader('content-length', res.headers['content-length']);
      webResponse.setHeader('cache-control', res.headers['cache-control']);
      webResponse.setHeader('pragma', res.headers['pragma']);
      webResponse.setHeader('connection', res.headers['connection']);
      webResponse.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":res.headers['content-type']});
      webResponse.end(body, 'binary');
    }else{
      webResponse.end('Image pull failed');
    }
    //console.log(res.statusCode);
  });
```